# Marshal C# string to C++ tchar through streamwriter

Tags: c#, encoding, pinvoke, tchar

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684936/named-pipe-between-csharp-and-c)

In C++, I require a TCHAR string (LPTSTR).
C# StreamWriters can output ASCII, Unicode, UTF32, etc... Not TCHAR strings.

I am not calling a function in C++, I am sending a string message over a named pipe.

C#:

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "mynamedpipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient, Encoding.UTF8))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient, Encoding.Unicode))
{
    pipeClient.Connect();
    pipeClient.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
    sw.Write("Howdy from Kansas");
    sw.Flush();

    var b = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.Write(b);
}
```

C++ expects a TCHAR. Suggestions?

Comment: Remember that `TCHAR` is not really a definite type. It's a possibility of a type, after the programmer decides. See the [tchar tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tchar/info).

Comment: Are you really still coding for Windows 98? No other reason to use `TCHAR`?

Comment: No, sorry my windows C/C++ experience is spotty at best. It is apparently a wchar_t. I was confusing it with the likes of BSTR and com interop. I may be able to answer this question with some more trial&error.

Comment: @Deduplicator, you are right. How do you decide [TCHAR in DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363244.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, you actually need UTF-16 encoded text. That corrresponds to `Encoding.Unicode`. So you would use

```
new StreamWriter(pipeClient, Encoding.Unicode)
```

That said, you should also at least consider the issue of endianness. When transmitting data over a network I would expect you to convert to network byte order when ending, and convert to host byte order when receiving.

Comment: I need to find a bit more proof and I agree with you. I think it was nasty stream business that was interacting poorly with the message mode of pipes. I'll report back soon

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer since it does not use a streamwriter, as was the goal. Due to limitations though, this approach works just fine.

**Workaround:**

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "mynamedpipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
{
    pipeClient.Connect();
    pipeClient.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
    var msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Hello from Kansas!");
    pipeClient.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
}
```